# I'm testing code that uses deprecated functionality and I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: python, module, deprecated

Please take it easy on me, even though this might be a simple question, I'm new to Python and coding in general. I'm testing some code out that I found on Github for deep learning. The code uses the following function:

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
    labels,
    logits,
    axis=None,
    name=None,
    dim=None
)
```

The docs for this function say this:

```
Computes softmax cross entropy between logits and labels. (deprecated arguments)
```

and this:

```
Warning: SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED: (dim). They will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: dim is deprecated, use axis instead
```

What's the solution in this situation? Unfortunately, the code I'm testing is too advanced for me to understand, so I can't "rewrite" it using other functionality etc... I'm just testing it out to use it as is in a project I'm working on.

I've heard something about reverting back to an old version, I'm not sure what this is about, how to go about it, and whether or not it applies here. If it doesn't what are other ways to deal with this problem given my limited knowledge of the code?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2), as you yourself noted.

When something is deprecated, that means that it will be removed soon (how soon depends on the developer), and therefore it is marked as deprecated so that consumers will be able to change their code before it breaks.

In this case, `dim` and `axis`, per the documentation, actually do the same thing, so just use `axis` and ignore `dim`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So the code is not really using dim or axis. Here is the call to the function in the code: ce_loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=conv_out, labels=labels_one_hot). The problem is with logits and labels, which are deprecated according to what I mentioned above. What should I do in this case? (P.S the docs don't mention what to do here)

Comment: @user10796158 I think there might be some misunderstanding here. What that sentence means is more something like "This function does this, and, oh, by the way, some of its arguments are deprecated; namely, `dim`". `logits` and `labels` are not deprecated.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. But then why does it throw the error? I'm not using any of dim and axis in the function call (only logits and labels)

Comment: Let me include the error by the way. Here it is: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.nn' has no attribute 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2'

Comment: @user10796158 That sounds like you're using the wrong TensorFlow version.